Nested If statement. working in two sheets
its been a long time since I used Excell so my thinking may be complety wrong, but this wont work. Am I using the wrong Syntax for LibreOffice Calc
=IF(M3>$'Shipping Profile'.$A$3,then $'Shipping Profile'.$B$3,
IF(M3>$'shipping profile'.$A$4,then'Shipping Profile'.$B$4,
IF(M3<$'Shipping Profile'.$A$5,then$'Shipping Profile'.$B$5,)))

Shiping Profile is a sheet in the same work book

get rid of all the references to then it's implied in the formula. (otherwise you would need to use else also)

The syntax for IF should be
=IF( condition, true_result, false_result )

However, since you've got nested IF statements you may prefer to use IFS:
=IFS(M3>$'shipping profile'.$A$3, $'shipping profile'.$B$3, M3>$'shipping profile'.$A$4, $'shipping profile'.$B$4, M3<$'shipping profile'.$A$5, $'shipping profile'.$B$5)

The syntax for IFS is a list of (condition, result) pairs:
=IFS( condition_1, result_1, condition_2, result_2, …, condition_N, result_N )

And if you want the equivalent of else, use a TRUE condition at the end of the list.
Note that in both Excel and LibreCalc, as you start to enter a formula the application will prompt you with the structure and short description of the expected parameters.
